# Why will my exception not print out its print statement? (Java)

Tags: java, exception, printing, try-catch, do-while

The print statement in my exception never prints out. If I do not enter anything it will just continue to ask me to enter name of cruise ship. I need it to throw the exception print statement along with that if someone were to enter an empty string or anything other than a string.

```
 do {
  try {
      System.out.println("Enter name of cruise ship: ");
      cruiseShipName = scnr.nextLine();

      }
  catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please try again.");
    }
} while (cruiseShipName.equals(""));
```

Comment: What did the debugger tell you? When you step through your code line-by-line what do you learn?

Comment: If you want to check if the input is empty, you want an `if` statement, not a `catch`.

Comment: When I run the code it doesn't give me an error. It runs smoothly, I just need it to print out differently than what it is doing.

Comment: No line here can throw an exception. So the control never enters the catch block. Maybe skip the try catch approach and add a simple validation on the `cruiseShipName` variable

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your code will not throw any exception if the scnr.nextLine() is empty.

In your case if you want to ask the user to try again, you could do as following:

`

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter name of cruise ship: ");
    cruiseShipName = scnr.nextLine();
    if (cruiseShipName.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please try again.");
    }
} while (cruiseShipName.equals(""));
```

`

Comment: This is the proper way to do it. No need for exceptions here. Simply tell the user they've entered something invalid, and let them try again.

Answer (score 0):

The may help you.

```
do {
  try {
      System.out.println("Enter name of cruise ship: ");
      cruiseShipName = scnr.nextLine();
      if(cruiseShipName.equals("")) throw new Exception("");
      }
  catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please try again.");
    }
} while (cruiseShipName.equals(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't actually throw an exception.  You don't have anything that checks if the input is valid and throws an exception if it isn't.

So right now, the input is *always* valid.